# Error while trying to clean install, 409 conflict

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, gitlab, artifactory

I'm trying to integrate jFrog with Gitlab, working with maven and spring framework
I have this error when doing the commit

[image]

This is the pom.xml I'm using

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.engine</groupId>
    <artifactId>enginebe</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>enginebe</name>
    <description>enginebe</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>xxxx-libs-snapshot</name>
            <url>https://xxx.jfrog.io/artifactory/xxx-libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And the gitlab pipeline is like this

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
image: maven:latest
before_script:
  # Install JFrog CLI
  -  curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh
  # Configure Artifactory instance with JFrog CLI
  - ./jfrog rt config --url=$ARTIFACTORY_URL --user=$ARTIFACTORY_USER --password=$ARTIFACTORY_PASS
  - ./jfrog rt c show
  # Set the M2_HOME environment variable
  - export M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven
  # Replace the repository name in the configuration.yml to the correct one.
  - sed -i 's,MAVEN_REPO_KEY,'"$MAVEN_REPO_KEY"',g' configuration.yml
build:
  script:
    # Run the MVN command
    - ./jfrog rt mvn "clean install" configuration.yml --build-name=gitlabci-maven-artifactory --build-number=$CI_JOB_ID
    # Collect the environment variables
    - ./jfrog rt bce gitlabci-maven-artifactory $CI_JOB_ID
    # Pass the build information to Artifactory
    - ./jfrog rt bp gitlabci-maven-artifactory $CI_JOB_ID
  only:
    - main
```

I know the problem due to , pom.xml not specified, I'm not sure if I should add something to jFrog or just change something to the pom.xml file

I tried mvn deploy in the terminal and it was successful, it deployed the jar and pom to the artifactory, but with gitlab pipeline it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 409 error you receive indicates an issue with the pom.xml.
In the pom.xml above I noticed you added "relativePath" closure but without opening it or specifying it. I think the pom validator doesn't like that.

Regardless, you can tell Artifactory to ignore this kind of issue by ticking the "Suppress POM Consistency" box in the repository configuration page.

For more information on this flag, you can read JFrog documentation [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Local+Repositories#LocalRepositories-Maven,Gradle,IvyandSBTRepositories).